# Applying early binding on COM object in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, com, early-binding

I'm using VBA macro to get data from 3rd part program named Simpack. Simpack supports the COM-interface. But how is it possible to learn early binding naming of program. For my current process i'm connecting with late binding such a type;

```
Dim Srv As Object
Set Srv = CreateObject("Simpack.Slv.2018x")
```

But i don't how really i can using early binding on Simpack. I tried this but didn't work because i think usage of `Simpack.Application` is wrong.

```
Dim Srv As Simpack.Application
Set oAPP = New Simpack.Application
```

I checked program documentation and found below information i don't know is it useful information or not for my situation.

Documentation:
An object of this class has to be created by the COM client's COM implementation.

Each COM client platform provides its own means to create an instance of this object. Please refer to your platform's documentation for general COM questions.

In JavaScript running on Windows Scripting Host, you can use:

```
var slv = WScript.CreateObject("Simpack.Slv");
```

or

```
var sut = new ActiveXObject("Simpack.Slv");
```

On .Net using C#, you have to add a reference to the COM server in your project first. To create a server instance, use

```
SpckCOMApp app = new simpackcomguiLib.SpckCOMApp();
```

Comment: Have you added the reference? If so, have a look in the Object Browser (F2)

Comment: @Sam yeah reference added. I looked from Object Browser all objects seems without any problem. Only my problem how to learn Early Binding naming structure.

Comment: Perhaps this article [Early vs. Late Binding](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/EarlyLateBinding.html) may be helpful. It seems that early binding can be used by registering a COM object in References of Tools.

Comment: @kunif sorry for late response but thats really good to understand.